# While loop with input is not displaying any kind of prompt for input or result

Tags: java, loops, intellij-idea, while-loop, count

I am currently writing a program as practice for class, where the user is prompted to input a series of numbers, where the input should end with 0. The program should be able to add one to the variable positive sum when it comes into contact with a positive number from the input. The program should be able to add one to the variable negative sum when it comes into contact with a negative number from the input. The program should add all of these numbers together in order to get total. The program should be able to get the average and display it as a double.

When I do try running the program, I get a pathway to the directory in which intellij is held in my downloads folder.

I'm not necessarily sure what I could try differently. No error warnings are popping up in my IDE.

This is my code:

`   import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class LoopPractice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
//create scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int positiveSum = 0;
    int negativeSum = 0;
    int numberOfPositive = 0;
    int numberOfNegative = 0;
    int totalNumbers = 0;
    int integers = input.nextInt();

    while(integers != 0){
        System.out.println("Enter integers ending with 0: ");
        integers = input.nextInt();

            if (integers > 0) {
                positiveSum += integers;
                numberOfPositive++;
                totalNumbers++;
                System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positiveSum);

            } else  if (integers < 0) {
                negativeSum += integers;
                numberOfNegative++;
                totalNumbers++;
                System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negativeSum);
            }
        double average =  (numberOfPositive + numberOfNegative) / totalNumbers;
        System.out.println("The total is: " + totalNumbers);
            System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
            }
        }
     }
```

`

Comment: Replace `int integers = input.nextInt();` with `int integers = 1;` .  The scanner usage there is preventing the normal sequence of "prompt followed by input" that you have designed.  Setting it to `1` simply allows your loop to enter the first time - after that the scanner input dictates the loop.  Also maybe add a message once you exit the loop to indicate the program has finished.

Comment: Also, I suspect your average calculation is not what is needed - if you need help with that I suggest adding some test data with expected results with your next question.

Comment: you might want to make integers into an `int[]` array

Comment: By the way, a good question like this should have examples, where each example has input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: **1st:** Off-topic critique: You have `Enter integers ending with 0:` before `integers = input.nextInt();` inside the while loop. Why not have it also before `integers = input.nextInt();` before the `while` loop? Why not be consistent with prompting the user? **2nd:** You are throwing away the first value the user inputs. Is that what you intended?  Note there is no prompt for the user. Try running the program. If it seems to hang up, try entering a number.  **3rd** Consider using a `do { ... } while ( ... )` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute your code, it stops at

"int integers = input.nextInt();"

and expects you to provide an input before moving down the loop. You invoked nextInt() method while declaring int variable and hence the scanner is expecting an int input. That is why you see a blank after intellij directory.

I adjusted your code a little bit while keeping rest of it same.I printed a statement before you declaring integers variable. So, that the first input you provide counts when you move inside the loop, once a loop is at end, we again check for new input.(Alternatively, you can go with do while loop as Reilas suggested)

changed few variable names numberOfPositive > positiveEntries. . .etc.

---

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int positiveSum = 0;
    int negativeSum = 0;
    int PositveEntries = 0;
    int NegativeEntries = 0;
    int totalEntries = 0;
    int totalSum;
    double average;



    System.out.println("Enter integers ending with 0: ");
    int integers = input.nextInt();

    while(integers != 0){



        if (integers > 0) {
            positiveSum += integers;
            PositveEntries++;
            totalEntries++;
            System.out.println("Sum of positive entries " + positiveSum);

        } else  if (integers < 0) {
            negativeSum += integers;
            NegativeEntries++;
            totalEntries++;
            System.out.println("Sum of negative entries " + negativeSum);
        }
        totalSum = positiveSum + negativeSum;
        average =  totalSum / totalEntries;
        System.out.println("Total sum = " + totalSum + ". Average = "+ average);

        System.out.println("Enter another sum or enter 0 to terminate");
        integers = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("program terminated");



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a *do-while loop*, and a *boolean*.

Additionally, you can use the *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)* class for *positiveSum* and *negativeSum*.

Here is an example.

```java
import static java.math.BigInteger.ZERO;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int i;
BigInteger x, a = ZERO, b = ZERO;
boolean exit = false;
do {
    x = in.nextBigInteger();
    i = x.compareTo(ZERO);
    if (i == 0) exit = true;
    else if (i < 0) a = a.add(x);
    else b = b.add(x);
} while (!exit);
```

Output

```
1 2 3 -4 -5 -6 0
a = -15
b = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

`"When I do try running the program, I get a pathway to the directory in which intellij is held in my downloads folder."`

I have absolutely no idea what you mean by that :/ but, it seems more like an IntelliJ setup issue rather than an actual code problem which you do have. How are you running the code to have this particular issue? Explain that in you posted question.

---

Below is an example runnable that explains how this can be done with User Input Validation (read the comments in code - The comments make the code look like quite a bit but really it isn't. You can delete them when your done with them if you like:

The only Scanner method used in the demo is the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method which I think provides better input control but that's just my opinion. To carry out User Input Validation, the demo utilizes the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method which is passed a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex): `"-?\\d+"` and this is basically what it means:

- `-?` The numerical string may, or may not, start with the minus
  character indicating whether or not the string value is signed
  (negative if it's there) or unsigned (positive if it's not there);
- `\\d+` The numerical string contains *one or more* numerical digits
  from **0** to **9** *only*.

```
public class LoopPractice {
    // A variable to hold the OS dependent newline character sequence:
    private final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    
    // Declare a Scanner Object:
    private java.util.Scanner input;

    
    // Application Entry Point:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App is opened this way to avoid the need for 
           statics (unless we want them):        */
        new LoopPractice().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* Open a keyboard input stream. Do Not close this particular stream!
           The JVM will close this resource automatically when the application 
           closes.        */
        input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        
        // A List Interface of Integer to hold supplied unsigned (positive)integer numbers:
        java.util.List<Integer> unsignedInts = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        
        // A List Interface of Integer to hold supplied signed (negative) integer numbers:
        java.util.List<Integer> signedInts = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        
        // Will hold the actual valid integer number supplied once converted:
        int intNumber;
        
        /* Will hold the current prompt count so the User always
           knows what the numbers count is they are currently
           working on:        */
        int cnt = 0; 
        
        /* This variable will actually hold the User's numerical input
           and yes, it is of type String. I like to accept string input
           from the User because I think it's easier to validate and 
           other things like "(q to quit)" can be added to the prompt.
           There should be no need to catch Exceptions for input 
           validation:        */
        String numString;
        
        /* Boolean Flag used as the condition for the outer `while` 
           loop. If false, we keep looping. If true, we exit the 
           loop:                   */
        boolean quit = false;
       
        /* Describe what is "expeted" from the User. 
           This greatly helps the User make proper 
           entries:                            */
        System.out.println("Enter a series of valid signed or unsigned integers." + ls
                         + "All the numbers you supply MUST end with 0 otherwise" + ls
                         + "that number will be considered Invalid and you will " + ls
                         + "need to re-enter the desired number. Entering just 0" + ls
                         + "is Invalid as is any number that contains alpha type " + ls
                         + "characters. The integer numbers you supply can not be" + ls
                         + "less than the value of  -2147483648  and, can not be " + ls
                         + "greater than the value of 2147483647:" + ls);
       // Keep looping while the `quit` variable holds false:
        while (!quit) {
            numString = ""; // Set `numString` to Null String (""):
            
            /* Keep looping while the `numString` variable is 
               Empty (holds Null String(""):            */
            while (numString.isEmpty()) {
                cnt++;  // Increment the prompt counter by 1
                // Display the prompt to User:
                System.out.print("Enter Integer #" + cnt + " (or q to quit): -> ");
                
                /* Get keyboard input from User. The code halts here
                   and waits for the User to enter something from the 
                   keyboard and hit the ENTER key:                */
                numString = input.nextLine().trim();
                
                // Is quit desired......
                if (numString.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    /* Yes...set the `quit` variable to boolean true 
                       and exit this inner loop:                */
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                }
                
                // INPUT VALIDATION:
                /* Is the supplied string representation of a numerical 
                   value a signed or unsigned integer value which contains 
                   a 0 on the end, is greater than Integer.MIN_VALUE (-2147483648)
                   and is less than Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647), and 
                   finally, is not just 0:
                */
                if (!numString.matches("-?\\d+") || !numString.endsWith("0")
                                                 || Long.parseLong(numString) < Integer.MIN_VALUE
                                                 || Long.parseLong(numString) > Integer.MAX_VALUE
                                                 || Integer.parseInt(numString) == 0) {
                    // NO...Inform the User of an Invalid Entry and to try again...
                    System.out.println("Invalid Numerical Entry (" + numString + ")! - Try again..." + ls);
                    // Decrement the prompt counter because of an Invalid Entry:
                    cnt--; 
                    /* Empty the `numString` variable to ensure re-loop
                       so the User can try again:             */
                    numString = "";
                }
            }
            
            /* If we get to this point then either `q` for quit 
               was entered or a VALID integer value was supplied.  */
            if (quit) {
                continue;
            }
            
            // Convert the String numerical value to int:
            intNumber = Integer.parseInt(numString);
            
            /* If the supplied integer number is greater than 0
               then the value supplied is an unsigned (positive)
               integer number so, add it to the `unsignedInts`
               List otherwise add it to the   `signedInts` List.
               We know it can't be 0 because that wouldn't have
               passed validation: We used an `if` statement with 
               Ternary Operator for this:               */
            if (intNumber > 0 ? unsignedInts.add(intNumber) : signedInts.add(intNumber));
        }
        
        /* Count the total number of Integer values the User supplied.
           These values are held within the `unsignedInts` and the 
           `signedInts` Lists so, to find out how many VALID numbers
           were entered, we sum together the size of both lists:   */
        int totalNumberOfInts = (unsignedInts.size() + signedInts.size());
        
        /* If both Lists contain nothing then `totalNumberOfInts` would
           contain 0. Chances are, the `q` for quit was supplied before 
           any valid integer numbers could be established so, inform the
           User that there is nothing to report and return which will
           effectively end the application (or the entry session):   */
        if (totalNumberOfInts == 0) {
            System.out.println("No Results To Show!" + ls + "Quiting - Bye Bye");
            return;
        }
        
        // Otherwise, report the results of the values that were entered then quit.
        
        // Sum the values containd within the `unsignedInts` List:
        int sumOfUnsignedIntegers = unsignedInts.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        
        // Sum the values containd within the `signedInts` List:
        int sumOfSignedIntegers = signedInts.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        
        // Acquire the Overall Sum of the two Lists:
        int overallSum = (sumOfUnsignedIntegers + sumOfSignedIntegers);
        
        // Start displaying the calcualted results into the Console Window:
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The total number integers supplied was:            " 
                            + totalNumberOfInts);
        System.out.println("The number of unsigned (positive) integers is:     " 
                            + unsignedInts.size() + "  ->  " + unsignedInts);
        System.out.println("The number of signed (negative) integers is:       " 
                            + signedInts.size() + "  ->  " + signedInts);
        System.out.println("The total sum of unsigned integers is:             " 
                            + sumOfUnsignedIntegers);
        System.out.println("The total sum of signed (negative) integers is:    " 
                            + sumOfSignedIntegers);
        System.out.println("The overall total sum of all supplied integers is: " 
                            + overallSum);
        
        // Calculate the Average (cast the int's to doubles):
        double average = ((double)overallSum / (double)totalNumberOfInts);
        
        // Display the Average within the Console Window:
        System.out.println("The overall Average is:                            " 
                            + average);
        
        // Inform of Quiting:
        System.out.println(ls + "Quiting - Bye Bye" + ls);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I have ADHD; sometimes the words in my head don't come out the way I want them to. Thank you for your help :).